# Passing an atomic variable to a function

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I am trying to pass an atomic variable to a function as follow:

```
 // function factor receives an atomic variable 
 void factor(std::atomic<int> ThreadsCounter)
 {
  .........
 }


 // main starts here
 int main()
 {
 // Atomic variable declaration
 std::atomic<int> ThreadsCounter(0);
 // passing atomic variable to the function factor through a thread
 Threadlist[0] = std::thread (factor, std::ref(ThreadsCounter));
 Threadlist[0].join();
 return 0;
 }
```

When running the above code, I was getting the following error:

> Error 2   error C2280: 'std::atomic::atomic(const std::atomic &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional   1149    1   klu_factor

Anyone knows how to fix this ? your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `factor` takes it's `ThreadsCounter` parameter by value, and `std::atomic` is not copy constructable.

Eeven though you bound a reference to your thread function, it's attempting to create a copy to pass the function.

Comment: @ Collin Dauphinee , I just tried to modify the function as 'void factor(std::atomic<int> &ThreadsCounter)' and I got the same error

Comment: I just compiled and ran your test case, double check that you actually built the changes.

Comment: Yes my bad, I modified the source file but not the header file. It works now thank you

Comment: @ Collin Dauphinee, what is the best way to increment the atomic variable in the function. Sorry I am still new to atomic variables